# How to return a value from __init__ in Python?

Tags: python, class, init

I have a class with an `__init__` function.

How can I return an integer value from this function when an object is created?

I wrote a program, where `__init__` does command line parsing and I need to have some value set. Is it OK set it in global variable and use it in other member functions? If so how to do that? So far, I declared a variable outside class. and setting it one function doesn't reflect in other function ??

Comment: If you were considering returning an error code, raise an exception instead.

Comment: Please remove your comment and update your question.  You own the question.  It's your question.  Please fix the question to correctly show what your real problem is.  You're misusing `__init__`; we can help you if you describe what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: `__init__` probably should *not* be doing command-line parsing. Define a class method that does the actual parsing, and pass the parsed values to `__init__`. Let `__init__` worry about creating the necessary attributes, not figuring out how to produce the values for those attributes.

Comment: Note for future readers: If you want to get generic information back as a result of calling `__init__`, see the answers given here. If you want to *signal that something went wrong*, raise an exception. That doesn't answer the question that was asked here, but might be what you have in mind.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`__init__` is required to return None. You cannot (or at least shouldn't) return something else.

Try making whatever you want to return an instance variable (or function).

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         return 42
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None
```

Comment: +1: You **cannot** return something else.  It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: __init__ doesn't return the newly created object - as seen in the TypeError, it is required to return None, right?  The newly created object is returned by __new__, __init__ just sets some of its attributes. But yes, as you said, changing __init__, or __new__, to return something else really makes no sense.

Comment: Where is `new` here? Is `new` implicit in Python? I assumed Python's semantics were different from Java and the other languages that do use this word.

Comment: @Shiva AFAIK, by new weronika meant __new__(self) not the general java semantic.

Comment: Just because it can't be done doesn't mean it doesn't make sense. It would, for instance, be nice to pass data from `super().__init__` to the derived class without having to relay it through an instance variable.

Comment: __init__ should not return anything, included None. If you are adding typing, the ones for __init__ must be NoReturn.

Comment: May I know how the `pd.DataFrame({something})` returns output? How that can be able to call other class methods

Answer (score 211):

If you want to return some other object when a class is called, then use the `__new__()` method:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("never called in this case")

    def __new__(cls):
        return 42

obj = MyClass()
print(obj)
# Output: 42
```

Comment: Yeah, __new__ is the right way of returning something other than a class instance when using a class... I'm just wondering - is there any reason you might actually want to DO that?

Comment: @weronika One idea: in any situation where you'd normally use a factory, but you have some reason to want to present an interface that looks like normal class instantiation. Example: when adding some new optional parameters into your class's `__init__`, you realise that really, to provide the flexibility you want, you need a class factory that returns instances of specialised subclasses. But your library's users are already using your existing API. To preserve it, you override `__new__` to return instances of your specialised subclasses.

Comment: If you want to see an example of what Mark Amery said, check out the source code of the `datetime` module from the Standard Library.  It uses `__new__` in exactly this fashion.

Comment: Also if anyone wants to do this make sure to inherit from object otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I kind of think at this pount, just using a regular function makes more sense. Might be a bit alien to folks from the Java dimension (functions not in classes? heresy!) but its pythonic. (Also you can assign properties to functions as in funtionName.val =.. which is kind of wild but it works)

Answer (score 45):

From the [documentation of `__init__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

> *As a special constraint on constructors, no value may be returned; doing so will cause a TypeError to be raised at runtime.*

As a proof, this code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        return 2

f = Foo()
```

Gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_init.py", line 5, in <module>
    f = Foo()
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'int'
```

Answer (score 24):

Sample Usage of the matter in question can be like:

```
class SampleObject(object):

    def __new__(cls, item):
        if cls.IsValid(item):
            return super(SampleObject, cls).__new__(cls)
        else:
            return None

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.InitData(item) #large amount of data and very complex calculations

...

ValidObjects = []
for i in data:
    item = SampleObject(i)
    if item:             # in case the i data is valid for the sample object
        ValidObjects.append(item)
```

Comment: This will raise a NameError: `self` is not defined in `__new__(cls, Item)`

Answer (score 16):

The `__init__` method, like other methods and functions returns None by default in the absence of a return statement, so you can write it like either of these:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=42

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=42
        return None
```

But, of course, adding the `return None` doesn't buy you anything.

I'm not sure what you are after, but you might be interested in one of these:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=42
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

f=Foo()
print f.value
print f
```

prints:

```
42
42
```

Comment: ohh..Can i access member variable out the class ? Then that should solve my issue ....thanks

Comment: @lakshmipathi, Yes, instance variables like this are public.

Comment: As a oneliner to get something valuable returned after initiation of a class: `f = Foo().value`

Comment: @JLT Yes, you cam always do that but it still does not mean that anything is returned from `__init__`.

Answer (score 11):

`__init__` doesn't return anything and should always return `None`.

Answer (score 6):

You can just set it to a class variable and read it from the main program:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        #Do your stuff here
        self.returncode = 42
bar = Foo()
baz = bar.returncode
```

Answer (score 4):

We can not return value from init. But we can return value using **new**.

```
class Car:
    def __new__(cls, speed, unit):
        return (f"{speed} with unit {unit}")


car = Car(42, "km")
print(car)
```

Comment: Yes, but you can't really return arbitrary values from `__new__` and still have the class "protocol" make sense.

Answer (score 2):

## **init**() return none value solved perfectly

```
class Solve:
def __init__(self,w,d):
    self.value=w
    self.unit=d
def __str__(self):
    return str("my speed is "+str(self.value)+" "+str(self.unit))
ob=Solve(21,'kmh')
print (ob)
```

output:
my speed is 21 kmh

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, you can return classes in `__init__`

```
@property
def failureException(self):
    class MyCustomException(AssertionError):
        def __init__(self_, *args, **kwargs):
            *** Your code here ***
            return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    MyCustomException.__name__ = AssertionError.__name__
    return MyCustomException
```

The above method helps you implement a specific action upon an Exception in your test

Comment: `super().__init__` is returning `None`, so you are returning `None`, which is fine, but redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Met this case when tried to parse some string data into a recursive data structure, and had a counter to be passed through.

Python does not allow to return anything from `__init__`, but you may write a factory function, or a class method, or a `Parser` class, depending on the code structure and complexity of parsing, which will parse your data into data objects.

Global variable is not a good solution, as it may be changed somewhere else, breaking the parsing logic.

Function example:

```python
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        # only assignments here
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        # return None


def parse(data):
    # parsing here
    a = ...
    b = ...
    c = ...

    # status, counter, etc.
    i = ...

    # create an object
    my_obj = MyClass(a, b, c)
    
    # return both
    return my_obj, i


# get data and parse
data = ...
my_obj, i = parse(data)
```

Class method example:

```python
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data):
        a = ...
        b = ...
        c = ...

        i = ...

        obj = cls(a, b, c)
        return obj, i


data = ...
my_obj, i = MyClass.parse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `__new__` is the best option, as mentioned in other answers.

Just to add a use case for why. The company I work for asked me to update our internal system from python 3.8 to 3.10 which runs on `Flask`, and with us still being on the 1.x.x version, I updated to 2.x.x, and that initially led to upgrading SQLAlchemy to version 2, but that created incompatibility issues around the use of `db.engine.execute()` calls that were all over the place still.

To fix this, I first tried a wrapper function to just replace the calls with the correct context-based engine calls, but that won't work for calls like:

`db.engine.execute(sql).scalar()`

because a function can't have a member function of it's own. So the solution was to create a class that could be called using both forms:

`DBEngineClass(sql)`

and

`DBEngineClass(sql).scalar()`

Where `DBEngineClass` has the `__new__` member function defined to return the pure `ResultProxy` from the engine call, whereas there is also a `scalar()` and `fetchall()` member function that relies on the `__init__` member function to execute the sql query and then set a `result` member variable to the `ResultProxy`, which can then be mutated and returned by the `scalar()` and `fetchall()` member functions.

So that way it reduces the overall time that we need to spend on refactoring, by making the process as simple as adding a new import statement into the affected python files, and then doing a simple find and replace to keep the same functionality, as well as make the system compatible with the newer version of `SQLAlchemy`.

Thanks for readind :-)

Answer (score -3):

**solution here**
Yes,
trying to return from the **init** method in python returns errors as it is a constructor of the class you can only assign values for the scope of the class but not return a specific value.
if you want to return a value but do not wish to create a method, you can use
**str** method

```
def __init__(self,a):
    self.value=a

   def __str__(self):
    return str("all my return values are possible here")`
```

Comment: `__init__` is the *initializer*, not the constructor. `__new__` is the constructor.

Comment: `__str__` has nothing to do with returning a value from the instantiation process.

Answer (score -4):

Well, if you don't care about the object instance anymore ... you can just replace it!

```
class MuaHaHa():
def __init__(self, ret):
    self=ret

print MuaHaHa('foo')=='foo'
```

Comment: That just changes what is assigned to the name `self` inside that constructor.