# Why object of python class returns address instead of return data?

Tags: python, class, object, repr

This is my first program in Python and I'm working with some API which is used to log in or register user.

This is how my class looks like:

```
class MyClass:
    ...
    def __init__(self, apikey, gameid, securitykey, responseformat, 
                 username=None, password=None, email=None)
        self.apikey = apikey
        self.gameid = gameid
        self.securitykey = securitykey
        self.responseformat = responseformat

        if username and password:
            self.userlogin(username,password)
        if username and password and email:
            self.userregistration(username, password, email)

    ''' And there are function userlogin and userregistration
    i'll show just one of them '''

    def userregistration(self, username, password, email):
        securitypayload = self.buildurl(username, password, email)
        user = requests.get('url', params = securitypayload)
        if 'error' in user.text:
            return user.text
        else:
            return 'Success!'
```

I tested this class with code below:

```
api_test = MyClass('apikeyadfasdf', 'gameiddfdfd', 'seckey34324324', 'JSON', 
                    'admin', 'pass1')
print(api_test)
```

and I got output like this:

```
<package1.package2.file_name.MyClass object at 0x7f278388b48>
```

But when I change my test to this:

```
api_test = MyClass('apikeyadfasdf', 'gameiddfdfd', 'seckey34324324', 'JSON', 
                    'admin', 'pass1')
data = api_test.userregistration(username, password, email)
print(data)
```

it'll do the thing and I'll get my output, but it'll execute that function two times.

I was thinking where the problem could be and I remembered that in JAVA you could get similar  output when you forget about override toString(). Now, I've read about python equivalents: **repr** and **str** but firstly I don't know how to return data from methods (not self.apikey etc.) and secondly I'm not 100% sure that is the right way to get my output, not address.

Comment: You have some indentation issues which I suspect are the result of pasting incorrectly or something. If you can check around `def userregistration(self...` etc... and see that that and subsequent lines are correctly indented, that would help.

Comment: Fixed. now it looks exactly like in my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem  is that you get the `userregistration` executed two times -- you execute it two times. Once in the `__init__` and once explicitly.

Regarding returning from `__init__` check SO "[How to return a value from __init__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491819/python-init-how-to-return-a-value)" :

> __init__ returns the newly created object. You cannot (or at least shouldn't) return something else.

And besides, don't use the return value to indicate error - use exceptions:

- [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)
- [Idioms and Anti-Idioms - Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#exceptions)

Comment: The problem is that I can't get normal output (from method in class) when I'm testing it like in first example. I know that in second test example it executed two times, I was just checking if it works, but this is unacceptable solution

Comment: Ok, now I get it. It was stupid question, sorry and thank you :)