# Make __init__ create other class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I created my own class `my_class` being initiated with two variables, `a` and `b`.

In case one attempts to create an object of `my_class` with `a==b`, I would like that object to simply be of `type(a)` and not `my_class`.

How can this be implemented? How would the following implementation need to be modified?

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        if a == b:
            self = a
        else:
            myclass.a = a
            myclass.b = b
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in the constructor? I would find this very confusing as a user of your class. Why dont you just make a free function that returns the correct object?

Comment: Not recommended at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people say in the comment, I also think is not recommended.
But if you really need to do it this way, this code should do it:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if a == b:
            return a
        else:
            instance = super(myclass, cls).__new__(cls)
            return instance

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

You can test it:

```
x = myclass(4, 4)
y = myclass(4, 6)
print(x) #this prints 4
print(y) #this prints <__main__.myclass object at ...>
print(y.a, y.b) #this prints 4 6
```

The fact is that `__init__` cannot return anything, if you want to return something else you shoud use `__new__`

See also: [How to return a value from __init__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491819/how-to-return-a-value-from-init-in-python)