# Why does Init function return Object type but other functions return the NoneType

Tags: python, class, oop, object, nonetype

I wrote a python program to try to grade my ml predictions using object oriented programming and I am trying to chain functions together. Like say:

```
answers = predictionsGrader().merge_on('PassengerId').compare("Survived_x", "Survived_y").grade()
```

However, my code started to throw errors of attribute error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compare'
```

After trying to understand what the problem was, I realized that although the initialization was returning an object,

```
<class 'predictionsGrader.predictionsGrader'>
```

the function which was called after the initialization (which is the `merge_on` function) was returning a `NoneType`

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Please what could be wrong. Here's the full code:

```
import pandas as pd

class predictionsGrader():

    def __init__(self, predictions, target):
        self.correct = []
        self.predictions = predictions
        self.target = target
        return


    def merge_on(self, row):
        self.row = row
        self.md = pd.merge(self.predictions, self.target, on=[self.row])
        return


    def compare(self, predicted_target, confirmed_target):
        self.predicted_target = predicted_target or "predicted_target"
        self.confirmed_target = confirmed_target or "confirmed_target"
        return


    def grade(self):
        for x in range(len(self.md[self.predicted_target])):
            if (self.md[self.predicted_target][x] == self.md[self.confirmed_target][x]):
                self.correct.append("right")
            else:
                self.correct.append("wrong")
        return self.correct
```

Comment: Because `__init__` is special (as are other double underscore functions). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491819/how-to-return-a-value-from-init-in-python.

Comment: If you *really* want to get what you are after, you can put `return self` at the end of your other methods. But I'd advise not to; at least not for regular methods that do not construct an object.

Comment: All methods return `None` by default. If you want to return something else, that is up to you. (btw your empty `return`s do nothing in your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a fluid interface like that, your methods (other than `__init__`) need to return `self`.

```py
class predictionsGrader():

    def __init__(self, predictions, target):
        self.correct = []
        self.predictions = predictions
        self.target = target

    def merge_on(self, row):
        self.row = row
        self.md = pd.merge(self.predictions, self.target, on=[self.row])
        return self

    def compare(self, predicted_target, confirmed_target):
        self.predicted_target = predicted_target or "predicted_target"
        self.confirmed_target = confirmed_target or "confirmed_target"
        return self

    def grade(self):
        for x in range(len(self.md[self.predicted_target])):
            if (self.md[self.predicted_target][x] == self.md[self.confirmed_target][x]):
                self.correct.append("right")
            else:
                self.correct.append("wrong")
        return self.correct
```

`__init__` shouldn't return anything - it's an initializer, not a constructor.

Comment: Solved it. Can't accept an answer for the next 10 minutes, but will do so the moment I can. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i'll remove the return from init

Comment: The problem with methods that alter the instance itself (i.e., it's attributes) and also return `self`, is that it can make it less obvious the instance was altered. Compare, for example, `list`, for which the `append` method returns `None`, especially because the list itself is altered (in place); the `__add__` method (`+`) for a list, in contrast, returns a new list. This is to avoid confusion API wise, in that it is clearer when the instance itself is altered, versus when an altered copy is returned. Return `self` from a method, therefore, doesn't feel very common to me.

Comment: Fluent interfaces aren't that commonly used by Pythonistas, that's true, but it's quite a common pattern elsewhere - see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface - any python is perfectly capable of it. I'm quite fond of the pattern in the right circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

`predictionsGrader()` is not same as `predictionsGrader.__init__()`. `__init__()` is called as part of the initiation process by some Python magic in the background.