# Why does Visual Studio Code insert "return super().__init__(self)" into the derived class?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I understand that [`__init__()` is required to return `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2491831/2555108), but when Visual Studio autocompletes a derived class `__init__()` for me, it does so like this:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Base')

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        return super().__init__()  # This part is added by VS Code
```

It's obviously not a syntax issue, as the Base `__init__` is returning `None`, which the derived class in turn returns as well.

But why even bother having that? What purpose does the return statement serve here?

Comment: Yea that's weird.

Comment: It might be doing that by default any time you call something in the parent class, regardless of whether it's `__init__` or a regular method? So it autocompletes it that way because that's how it generates a basic implementation of an inherited method.

Comment: Because VS Code is being stupid?  `__init__` should never return a value.  Add it to the 5000+ other bugs [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: @SimeonVisser You're correct, I just tried it with a non-dunder method and it exhibited the same result.

Comment: @wim It's still returning `None`, as long as `super().__init__` also correctly returns `None`. The explicit `return` is just redundant. (But yeah, VS Code is being stupid.)

Comment: But in VS Code's defense, it's a question of whether it's worth special-casing redundant but technically correct behavior. Since Python 3 *requires* `__init__` to return `None` now (in Python 2 the return value was simply ignored), I would say yes, it's worth special-casing.

Comment: @wim Did some digging, it's already been reported it seems: https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1082

Comment: I'm not a VS code enthusiast or anything but I do think calling it stupid because OP found a special case where it is behaving stupid is a bit harsh.

Comment: @d_kennetz Agreed, particularly because it's a bug with the Python extension, not with VS Code itself.

Comment: @d_kennetz I don't think anyone is calling the *developers* of VS Code stupid; it's an accurate description of the code, though, in the sense of "it hasn't been programmed to make a [smart] distinction between `__init__` and other functions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [@Simeon Visser's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435332/why-does-visual-studio-code-insert-return-super-init-self-into-the-deri/57435907#comment101348439_57435332), VS Code seems to do this for all inherited methods, and does not discriminate between `__init__()` and other methods. <del>An issue has [already been filed](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1082) in the Python Language Server repo.</del> The issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1082#event-2558057198).