# how value is passed from __init__ method in pyhton as it dose not return anyhting

Tags: python, constructor, initialization

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

bob = Person1('bob', 25)
```

`__init__` does not return anything so how are the values of properties name and age passed from `__init__` function  to the variable `bob` after assigning the properties `name` and `age` to the empty object `self`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a value from \_\_init\_\_ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491819/how-to-return-a-value-from-init-in-python)

Comment: `__init__` dosen't return anything, but in this case set to your instance the atributtes `name` and `age`, so you can use it

Comment: That is why `self` is passed in addition to the arguments. By the time `__init__` is called, the new object is already created and `__init__` just assigns its attributes to it

Answer (score 4):

`bob = Person1('bob', 25)` is really equivalent to something like

```
rv = Person1.__new__(Person1, 'bob', 25)
if isinstance(rv, Person1):
    rv.__init__('bob', 25)
bob = rv
```

Calling a class doesn't immediately call the `__init__` method. The class's `__new__` method is called first to actually create the new instance, and *if* `__new__` returns an instance of the class passed as the first argument, *then* `__init__` is called before returning the value.

---

Going a step further, this is all encapsulated in `type.__call__`, so really the call to `Person1('bob', 25)` is something like

```
bob = type.__call__(Person1, 'bob', 25)  # Person1 is an instance of type
```

where `type.__call__` is what calls `Person1.__new__` and, if appropriate, `Person.__init__`, and returns the resulting object for it to be assigned to `bob`.

Comment: In other words, an empty Person1 is being returned by __new__, at which point the class variables are set during the __init__

Comment: Not necessary empty; `__new__` itself can be overriden to do a lot of the same things `__init__` does. `__init__` exists because usually you don't have to be bothered to call a parent class's `__new__` method yourself first.