# return render(request, "product/products.html", {"products":products, "n_pages":n_pages}) ^ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a showcase site in Django, and I wanted to include a paging system in the product list, but I ran into this error.

views.py

```
class articoloList(request):
    products = Product.objects.all
    paginator = Paginator(prodotti, 15)
    page = request.GET.get("pagina")
    n_pages = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, "product/products.html", {"products":products, "n_pages":n_pages})
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    img = models.ManyToManyField(Immagine)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marchio = models.ForeignKey(Marchio, related_name="marchi", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.date

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"pk":self.pk})
```

Thanks in advance!  :)

Comment: Well, you have a `return` statement that's not in a function... You're returning directly from a class, which you cannot do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a value from \_\_init\_\_ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491819/how-to-return-a-value-from-init-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
class articoloList(request):
    products = Product.objects.all
    paginator = Paginator(prodotti, 15)
    page = request.GET.get("pagina")
    n_pages = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, "product/products.html", {"products":products, "n_pages":n_pages})
```

to

```
def articoloList(request):
    products = Product.objects.all
    paginator = Paginator(prodotti, 15)
    page = request.GET.get("pagina")
    n_pages = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, "product/products.html", {"products":products, "n_pages":n_pages})
```